# Process Mining and Process Discovery using ProM

Tags: java, frameworks

I am new to this domain. My goal is to find similarities between event logs pattern. For this I have selected alpha algorithm. I have already seen videos about heuristic approach in ProM. But my confusion is that how can I implement this in my java project using ProM Framework/Plugin. Is this possible or not? Have I selected a right algorithm for this task?
As I said I am new to this domain, it would be very helpful for me if someone guide me about this stating step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not. ProM remain itself, not support to include any other project(such as java, web etc). you may make promM plugin to use your algorithm in promM, or create your own java project but would be implement process mining logic from bottom.

Comment: Thank you @DK2 for your response, 
Do you know other process discovery libraries which might help me?

Comment: try pm4py which is written in python. https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/

Comment: Thank you for you response but I am looking for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your ProM plugin as a class in java. You can also modify the current ProM plugins locally on your machine. However, using Alpha algorithm is not suitable for this task. There are plenty of plugins available that can help you in this regard. For example, if you consider directly follows relations as pattern, "Discover Matrix" plugin could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Is "Discover Matrix" is a ProM's plugin? I can find it under https://svn.win.tue.nl/repos/prom/Packages/

Comment: Yes, it is a plugin. It is already accessible via normal installation of ProM (not PromLite). The author of the plugin is Dr. Verbeek. You can ask him for more details via h.m.w.verbeek@tue.nl.

Comment: Thank you. i will check it.